# speech cards / palm cards

Tags: page-breaking, flashcards

I wish to print a document in the form of **speech/palm cards**.   That means, 
the text of the speech needs to be divided up by LaTeX automatically so that it fits into boxes of fixed dimensions (e.g.10cm by 8cm, landscape)  which I can then cut out with scissors later.  The cards would not overlap page-breaks, so I'd be able to fit about 3 cards per a4 page.

If possible, latex would begin new sections on new cards and be numbered.

I know I can use package `geometry` to change the size of the entire page, but that means only one card per page.

I don't have a useful MWE, but I imagine that the output would look like this:
[image: Imgur].

Comment: Do you use `sections` actually or is this just the number of the card?

Comment: I use sections too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the entire document inside [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram)es:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram,lipsum}

% \newflowframe[<page list>]{<width>}{<height>}{<x>}{<y>}[<label>]
\newflowframe{10cm}{8cm}{4cm}{16cm}% Top of page
\newflowframe{10cm}{8cm}{4cm}{7.5cm}% Middle of page
\newflowframe{10cm}{8cm}{4cm}{-1cm}% Bottom of page

\setallflowframes{border=plain}% Add frames to each flow frame

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution for me

Answer (score 2):

Since there's an overflow from one palm card to the next, you can do this in a two-stage process:

1. Create the document `palm_cards.pdf` with a geometry of 10cm x 8cm;
2. Merge `palm_cards.pdf` into a separate A4 page document using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).

Here would be what we do for (1) above:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=8cm,margin=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Use [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) to merge `palm_cards.pdf` into a new document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[nup=1x3,page=-,frame]{palm_cards}

\end{document}
```

Side note: The height of an A4 is 297mm < 30cm. You may have to change the geometry of `palm_cards.pdf`.

Comment: Using `pgfpages` allows the steps to be merged :)

Comment: @yo': Well isn't that just awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to create logical pages of size 10x8 and put them 3on1 a4 page using pgfpages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=10cm,
    paperheight=8cm,
    margin=2pt,
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[small,compact,bf,sf]{titlesec}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pgfpages,tikz}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{10x8 on a4}{
    \def\pgfpageoptionborder{1pt}
}{
    \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions{%
        logical pages=3,%
        physical height=297mm,
        physical width=210mm,
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{%
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{24cm},%
        border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\pgfstroke
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{%
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{16cm},%
        border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\pgfstroke
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{%
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{8cm},%
        border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}\pgfstroke
    }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{10x8 on a4}

\makeatletter
\clubpenalty0
\@clubpenalty0
\widowpenalty0
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```